# Django/Postgres: displaying distinct ManyToMany items

Tags: python, django, postgresql

Let's say for the sake of simplicity that I have three classes:

```
class BigThing(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=48)
    stufflists = models.ManyToManyField(StuffList)

class StuffList(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=48)
    stuff = models.ManyToManyField(Stuff)

class Stuff(models.Model):
   code = models.CharField(max_length=24)
   title = models.CharField(max_length=48)
   description = RedactorField(blank=True, null=True)
```

BigThing1 contains List1 and List3.

List1 contains Item1, Item2, Item3 in it.

List2 contains Item1, Item2, and Item4.

List3 contains only Item3.

I would like to return all of the Items that belong to BigThing1, omitting duplicates, like so:

```
Item1, Item2, Item3
NOT: Item1, Item2, Item3, Item3
(and obviously not Item4, since that doesn't belong to either of the lists associated with BigThing1)
```

I feel like there's something involving prefetch_related or select_related, but am kind of stumped because I'm new to Django/Postgres. In the past I would have done a JOIN query, but acknowledge that those queries are kind of hacks anyway, and would like to know the best practice for this kind of query, anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ManyToMany relationships can be followed backwards](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/#many-to-many-relationships) (specifically the section that starts "Reverse m2m queries are supported")

Something like the following should work

```
Stuff.objects.filter(stufflist__bigthing=BigThing1).distinct()
```

Comment: That was it! Thank you so much, I have no idea what was up with my mental block there.